# Does this ODE has a well known name?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying different methods to solve this differential equation analytically:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=C_0+C_1 x y^{n} +C_2 x^2 y^{m}+C_3 x^2 y^{q}  $$

Where $C_0,C_1,C_2,C_3,n,m,q$ are constants. 
Any ideas on what this ODE is called or, even better, which techniques might work better for solving it?

Comment: How do $n, m, q$ compare to each other?  For a solution approach, I would first try two things: (1) linearization near $x=0$: approximate $y(x) \doteq y_{0} + y_{1} x$, try to find the constant  $y_{1}$, and (2) the Laplace transform.

Comment: @avs The values do not have a certain pattern. They will be extracted form natural observations that could be any positive real number (although with my data-sets they never exceed 3).

Comment: @avs also, the problem with a linear approximation is that from numerical solutions I already know the solution can be very non-linear, and the non-linearity could happen anywhere in the domain. Do you think Laplace transform can still be useful?

Comment: On second thought, the powers of $y$ will probably give trouble with the Laplace transform.  Have you tried plotting the vector field (x, y) -> (x, dy/dx) and seeing its geometry?